# Swagger path paramType for dynamic parts spanning multiple /

Tags: swagger

I am using Swagger 1.2v in play framework. How I can use path parameter that is spanning multiple "/".

In my play framework routes file I have a route as

```
POST /v2/sample/*type
```

where *type can be

```
/v2/sample/free/2/3
```

or

```
/v2/sample/about/a/4
```

In my .java class I have use Swagger annotations as

```
@ApiImplicitParams({
     @ApiImplicitParam(name = "type", value = "Type Path Param",required = true, dataType = "String", paramType = "path"),
     @ApiImplicitParam(name = "Input", value = "Request body in JSON Format", defaultValue = "", required = true, dataType = "String", paramType = "body")
    })
```

but in the Swagger UI I am getting it as

```
POST /v2/sample/{type<.+>
```

Is there any solution or any workaround for this?

Comment: There's probably no way to do this because OpenAPI Specification [does not](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/892) [support](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/1459) slashes in path parameters.

Comment: Thanks Helen for a quick turnaround.